# Injecting host network into container in CircleCI

Tags: docker, networking, circleci

I have this CircleCI configuration.

```
version: 2
jobs:
    build:
        docker:
            - image: docker:18.09.2-git
            - image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
              name: elasticsearch

        working_directory: ~/project
        steps:
            - checkout
            - setup_remote_docker:
                docker_layer_caching: true

            - run:
                name: test
                command: |
                    docker run --rm \
                        --network host \
                        byrnedo/alpine-curl \
                        elasticsearch:9200
```

I'm looking for a way to allow my new container to access to the elasticsearch port 9200. With this configuration, the elasticsearch is not even a known host name.

- Creating an extra network is not possible, so I have this error message `container sharing network namespace with another container or host cannot be connected to any other network`
- Host network seems to be working **only** in the primary image

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

That will not work. Containers started during a build via the `docker run` command are running via a remote Docker engine. The cannot talk to the containers running as part of the executor via TCP since they are isolated. Just `docker exec`.

The solution will ultimately depend on your end goal, but one option might be to remove the Elasticsearch image/container from the executor, and use Docker Compose to get both images to talk to each other within the build.

Comment: Thanks for replying. In fact, I'm refactoring the whole file and removing Elasticsearch as a simple step build (working with simple networks) and adding it as part of the initial multi-image section. It works MUCH faster because it caches the images. That's the main goal I want to achieve :)